# Dagger hilt in multi moduled Application

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-room, dagger-hilt

I have a database module and a feature module. I placed my Room database implementation in the database module together with the repository interface and it's abstraction. I tried injecting the repository in my viewModel inside the feature module but it threw this error

```
  e: [ksp] ComponentProcessingStep was unable to process 'com.today.happy.MyApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC' because 'error.NonExistentClass' could not be resolved.
```

When I refactored the repository and moved it to the feature module, the error disappeared.

From the Dependency trace, dagger hilt doesn't find the dependency I am injecting into my viewModel. It's as if it's looking for it inside the feature module and not in the database module

```
  Dependency trace:
=> element (CLASS): com.today.home.ui.HomeViewModel
=> element (CONSTRUCTOR): HomeViewModel(error.NonExistentClass)
=> type (EXECUTABLE constructor): (error.NonExistentClass)void
=> type (ERROR parameter type): error.NonExistentClass
```

And yes, I have added the database module's dependency in the feature module.

Is there something I am missing about sharing dependencies across modules or what could be the problem with this?

Comment: You will need to share so code, sometimes we miss something small which is easily picked up by another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I did not add the database dependency to the app module. So important note is to always add modules that has dagger hilt to the app module or module with an entry point